# Prove a density probability function of a continuous random variable is nonnegative

Tags: probability

I tried to prove by contradiction, i.e. assuming there exists a value, called t, of the random variable such that PDF(t) is negative, and using definition of Reimann integral as infimum of upper Reimann sum to look for an inconsistence, but it went no where.

Update: I don't assume the pdf is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is only true if you assume that the density function, call it $f_X$, is continuous. Otherwise $f_X$ may be nonnegative on a set of Lebesgue measure zero. For a counterexample, let $E = \mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ and define $f_X:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ by
$$
f_X(x) = \mathsf 1_{[0,1]\setminus E}(x) - \mathsf 1_E(x).
$$
Then $f_X$ is not continuous at any $x\in[0,1]$, as any neighborhood of $x$ contained in $[0,1]$ has both rational and irrational numbers. However, this is not of any practical concern to the study of "continuous" random variables, because by definition the Lebesgue integral of a measurable function over a set of measure zero is zero. So we can safely ignore such pathological examples.

However, it is true that a density function $f_X$ cannot be negative on a set of positive measure. By definition of a probability density, we have that $\mathbb P(X\in B) = \int_B f_X\ \mathsf d\lambda$, where $B$ is a Borel set and $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure. Since $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure, in particular it is a positive measure, i.e. $\mathbb P(E)\geqslant 0$ for any event $E$. If there existed a set $N$ with $\lambda(N)>0$ and $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in N$, then we would have $$\mathbb P(X\in N)= \int_N f_X\ \mathsf d\lambda < 0, $$ a contradiction.